# Netbeans - Add library that is currently being edited

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working with multiple related projects in Netbeans. Is is possible to add a library or reference to that library (made from building one of the projects) to the other projects, while I'm still editing that library? I can 'clean & build' that library everytime I edit it and then import it again to the other projects, but that would be a really tedious task. Is there a way I can do it conveniently in Netbeans? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties -> libraries you can specify Jar/Folder, libraries or **other projects**. All changes in the pointing project will be available in your current project as you change it.

You still need to build it, but you don't need to import as Jar again.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the library group in your project you can add another project as a library.